# Mybatis - Returning ID on Upsert

Tags: postgresql, mybatis, ibatis, upsert

I have a statement configured that looks something like this (paraphrasing here, don't have the actual code in front of me):

```
<insert id="createRecord" parameterType="map">
  INSERT INTO MYTABLE (id, name, creator, description)
  VALUES (#{id}, #{name}, #{creator}, #{description})
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT (name, creator)
  DO UPDATE SET
    name = #{name},
    creator = #{creator},
    description = #{description}
</insert>
```

As it exists now, the application code generates the `id` itself by calling mybatis/postgres to get the next sequence value and then passes this to `createRecord`.

I want to refactor this code so that the `id` is created in `createRecord`.  To my knowledge, one way to do this is to replace `#{id}` in the statement with `nextval('my_seq')`.  Another way is using `selectKey`:

```
<insert id="createRecord" parameterType="map">
  <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="long">
    select nextval('my_seq')
  </selectKey>
  INSERT INTO MYTABLE (id, name, creator, description)
  VALUES (#{id}, #{name}, #{creator}, #{description})
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT (name, creator)
  DO UPDATE SET
    name = #{name},
    creator = #{creator},
    description = #{description}
</insert>
```

I want to be able to get the value of the id as a return value in both cases; whether it's a new record and a new sequence id was generated, or if there was a conflict/update, the existing id.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can return id if you rewrite the query like this:

```
<select id="createRecord" parameterType="map" resultType="long" flushCache="true">
  INSERT INTO MYTABLE (id, name, creator, description)
  VALUES (nextval('my_seq'), #{name}, #{creator}, #{description})
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT (name, creator)
  DO UPDATE SET
    name = #{name},
    creator = #{creator},
    description = #{description}
  RETURNING id
</insert>
```

This query now looks like select query that is it returns result and should be mapped as regular select query (but should use `flushCache` as it not read-only query).